# I'm looking for help integrating Paypal IPN's with Marklogic

Tags: utf-8, paypal-ipn, marklogic

I'm using ngrok to tunnel to my localhost. The IPN simulator runs smoothly, as does Postman. But once I run through the whole process (make a transaction, wait for IPN), I'm getting the following error: `400 XDMP-REQUTF8SEQ: Invalid UTF-8 escape sequence -- requests are not UTF-8 encoded`.

I put a xdmp:log at the entry point of the app and nothing was logged, so I believe the error occurs when the request hits the server. Is there a way to handle this at the server level? Has anyone had success integrating IPN's with ML?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The default for most REST endpoints is to expect a UTF-8 encoded payload. You can indicate the character encoding in the request headers. i.e. `Content-type: application/xml; charset=windows-1252`

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer:) In the IPN docs it says: `When testing using the IPN Simulator, the character encoding will always be UTF-8`. So if they're telling me that the messages will always be UTF-8 encoded when using the simulator, will the real messages be any different? Turns out that they just might be!

In the profile section of the PP account, click on "My Selling Tools" and scroll down to the bottom of the page. There should be a link that says "Paypal button language encoding". From there, click "More options" and you'll see what your options are. Mine was set up as "windows-1252". I guess that's what it is by default. Hope this helps someone else!